# Sharing data/memory between virtual machines

Tags: multithreading, virtual-machine, simulation, shared-memory

I'm working on designing a simulator for our control system.  There several functional areas with in the control system that need to be simulated.  For example, we need to simulate an electrical system and lets say an HVAC system.  The simulations are going to be on the simple side.
In real life, an HVAC system can't run if there isn't any power, so for the simulation, the HVAC model needs to know if there is power.

One approach we are looking at is to execute one functional area model on one virtual machine. Basically one VM per model.

Going back to my example, the electrical model will need to send some status to the HVAC model.  Is there a way to set up a shared memory area that all the VM's can access in order to share data?

I've read about virtual disks, internal networking between the VM's but I'm not sure if this will work for us because of the amount data that may need to be shared and the latency involved with those mechanisms.  Ideally, I think we need some type of global shared memory that each VM can read and write to.  Obviously the shared memory will need some type of mutex mechanism.

I'm not even sure if this approach is correct versus maybe using threading and kicking off one thread per model.

Comment: I think you'll find you're better off just using networking to communicate between the virtual machines.  Issues about getting different virtual machines to share memory aside, shared memory isn't a particularly useful method for communication, since even with shared memory you'll still need some mechanism for process A to let process B know that there is fresh data available; at which point you end up using standard networking anyway. A shared memory region is only worth it if the amount of data being generated is huge (e.g. multiple-megabytes-per-second or more), and even then it's a hassle.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  The more I thought about this, and I have gotten my thoughts crossed before, the amount of data that will need to be shared and the rate it will be changing shouldn't be that great.  There for, as you suggested, setting up an internal network between the VM's will probably be my best bet.